# Flutter column with spaceBetween leaves white space at the bottom

Tags: flutter, layout

so I have a column widget containing two items inside a container and I want these items to be spaced between so I added the `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` property to the column. It works as expected however I have a tiny white space at the end that I don't want.

The layout is the following :

```
Container(
    child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
            SizedBox(),
            TextButton()
        ]
    )
)
```

I already tried coloring the sizedBox to check if there was a white space at the top too, the answer is no. It is only happening at the bottom.

I also tried changing the widget from `TextButton` to `Text` only and the white space was gone.

Changing the `mainAxisAlignment` property to end didn't fixed the issue as well.

Here are two picture so that you can see what I am talking about :
[with the `TextButton` widget as last child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIBCQ.png) and
[exact same code but with a `Text` widget as last child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3XxE.png)

Comment: can you include an image pointing the issue

Comment: Alright, did it

Answer (score 0):

All the actions Widgets have a default padding/margin if you want a custom action use InkWell like this:

```
Container(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          color: Colors.redAccent,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print('abc');
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

[tiny white space has gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4gN5.png)

Let me know if this help :D

Comment: I will definitely remember this for the future as I will certainly use it, thanks !!!
For the moment I had the idea to wrap the TextButton with an Expanded widget and it fixed my issue